# UWP certificate

Tags: uwp, certificate, certificate-store

i'm trying to use a custom self-signed certificate for a UWP app. I followed the instructions in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing

As first step i manually changed the publisher in appxmanifest to match our company with all data, not only CN as the test certificate states.

After that i created a self-signed certificate using powershell as described. Even if not exporting the certificate to a file, it should be in my certificate store now. But when trying to selected a certificate from certificate store VisualStudio says there are no certificates that meet the application criteria.

I even made sure, that the enhanced properties are set correctly using certmgr.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

> it should be in my certificate store now. But when trying to selected a certificate from certificate store VisualStudio says there are no certificates that meet the application criteria.

After you create the .pfx file, the certificate is still not trusted by the local computer for deployment of app packages until you install it into the trusted certificates store of the local computer. You can refer to the following steps to  install it into the trusted certificates store.

**1. Find the certificate file and double click.**

**2. Select `Local Machine` option.**
[image]

**3. If your certificate has password, type the password for it.**

[image]

**4. Select `Automatically select the certificate store base on the type ofcertificate` option** .

[image]

**5. Finish**

**Usage**

Double click UWP project `Package.appcmanifest` ->Packaging button -> Choose Certificate -> Pick From certificate store. You will see the certificate that has been installed into certificates store.

[image]

Comment: Yes, another error message stating the same problem. Certificate is not accepted

Comment: yep, it is my nickname.

Comment: For me, I had to install the certificate to the "Current User" store (I already had it in the "Local Computer" store) before VS2017 would allow me to select it.

Comment: Followed these steps and doesn't show up for me either.

Comment: Try to sign a UWP for the store is one of the most confusing things I have ever come across in my life. I Have spend weeks on this, and now I have to renew, same problem. All the doco I can find is about test certificates. very very bad!

Comment: I disagree with step 4.  Instead of `Automatically select the certificate store` choose 'Place all certificates in the following store' and then browse to and select 'Trusted People'